# Android Fused Location API gives inaccurate Location in onLocationChanged

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation

I am struggling a little here, I am using Fused API for getting location updates. My intention is to draw a path on Map when user walks.

I have implemented that as follows :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);

        // some other initialization
        //....
        //
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        return view;
    }
```

then I start the stuff by following method

```
private void startReceivingLocationUpdates() {
        if (checkGPSPermission() && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !isReceivingLocationUpdates) {
            LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    locationRequest, this);
            isReceivingLocationUpdates = true;
        }
    }
```

& Here I receive the location update

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      if(getDistanceBetweenTwoLacation(mCoordinates.get(mCoordinates.size() - 1), location) > 3d) {
            for(int i= 0; i < mCoordinates.size(); i++) {
                Location locationTemp = mCoordinates.get(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "i => " + i + " Lat => " + String.valueOf(locationTemp.getLatitude()) + " Lng => " + String.valueOf(locationTemp.getLongitude()));
            }
            if(mCoordinates.size() > 0)
                Log.d(TAG, "lat difference is => " + getDistanceBetweenTwoLacation(mCoordinates.get(mCoordinates.size() - 1), location));
            mCoordinates.add(location);
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is , `onLocationChanged` gives location with lat-lng whose  difference/distance from past location is about 5-90 meters many times even if device is steady on same place. Am I missing something?

btw, here's the method which returns the distance from two lat-lngs which I used

```
private double getDistanceBetweenTwoLacation(Location origin, Location destination) {
        return origin.distanceTo(destination);
    }
```

Comment: Are you doing all this testing indoors?  If so, it's normal for it to jump around a lot.  Check the accuracy value and you'll see it's quite high, indicating a lot of uncertainty in position.

Comment: what permission do you have in the manifest?

Comment: @user3137702 yes, I am doing testing indoors...

Comment: @Matias Elorriaga here are the pemissions

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I suggest to try removing ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission

Comment: @sam_0829 I am facing the same issue, did you come across any solution for it ?

Comment: @AkshayJ If we are indoor, it's normal. you can check the Accuracy of location, if location accuracy is around 12-15, then you should consider that location otherwise ignore that location, moreover, you can check the speed from location object, if it's > 0, then take it into consideration, otherwise ignore the location,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inaccurate (and moving/drifting/jumping) GPS fixes when indoors is pretty common.  Without a clear view of the sky, an accurate GPS fix is impossible.  In your `Location` object, there is a `getAccuracy()` method which returns a float.  This value is the accuracy of the position fix in meters, wit 68% (1 standard deviation) confidence and represents the radius of a circle.

While indoors you will probably see an accuracy value of 20, 30, perhaps even 50 meters while the Lat & Long jump around within that distance.  Once outdoors, the accuracy value should drop to under 10 meters, often under 5 meters, and your position will jump around much less frequently.

tl;dr : GPS doesn't give accurate results indoors.